# Problem deploying portlets on JBoss Portal 2.7.2: Not a canonical value

Tags: jboss, portal, portlet, jboss-portal

I just downloaded the JBoss Portal Server 2.7.2 (JBoss Portal + JBoss AS 4.2.3 bundle to be precise) and tried deploying portlets just as the SimpleHelloWorld provided in the samples. The portlet gets deployed fine but when I put it on a page I get the following exception. I tried adding other Portlets as well (such as the booking MVC portelt supplied with Spring WebFlow dist) but the same problem happens.

The problem happens when the new instances are created by me, example when i create a new instance of CMS Portlet, I get the same error. If I use an existing instance it works. If I deploy a portlet that creates an instance using the "portle-instances.xml" then it works fine, but creating additional instances using the Admin and deploying them on page fails due to the following error.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone please help?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a canonical value  SimplestHelloWorldWindow
    org.jboss.portal.server.servlet.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:278)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a canonical value  SimplestHelloWorldWindow
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectPath$CanonicalFormat.parse(PortalObjectPath.java:357)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectPath.<init>(PortalObjectPath.java:161)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectPath.parse(PortalObjectPath.java:314)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectId.parse(PortalObjectId.java:158)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectId.parse(PortalObjectId.java:143)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.navstate.PortalObjectNavigationalStateContext.createWindowKey(PortalObjectNavigationalStateContext.java:299)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.navstate.PortalObjectNavigationalStateContext.getWindowNavigationalState(PortalObjectNavigationalStateContext.java:194)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.portlet.ControllerPageNavigationalState.getPortletWindowNavigationalState(ControllerPageNavigationalState.java:230)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.command.render.RenderWindowCommand.getPortletNavigationalState(RenderWindowCommand.java:121)
    org.jboss.portal.core.impl.model.content.InternalContentProvider.renderWindow(InternalContentProvider.java:211)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.command.render.RenderWindowCommand.execute(RenderWindowCommand.java:100)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerCommand$1.invoke(ControllerCommand.java:68)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:131)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.node.EventBroadcasterInterceptor.invoke(EventBroadcasterInterceptor.java:124)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.PageCustomizerInterceptor.invoke(PageCustomizerInterceptor.java:134)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.PolicyEnforcementInterceptor.invoke(PolicyEnforcementInterceptor.java:78)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.node.PortalNodeInterceptor.invoke(PortalNodeInterceptor.java:81)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.BackwardCompatibilityInterceptor.invoke(BackwardCompatibilityInterceptor.java:48)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.ControlInterceptor.invoke(ControlInterceptor.java:56)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.NavigationalStateInterceptor.invoke(NavigationalStateInterceptor.java:42)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ajax.AjaxInterceptor.invoke(AjaxInterceptor.java:55)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.ResourceAcquisitionInterceptor.invoke(ResourceAcquisitionInterceptor.java:50)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:157)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerContext.execute(ControllerContext.java:134)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.command.render.RenderWindowCommand.render(RenderWindowCommand.java:80)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.command.render.RenderPageCommand.execute(RenderPageCommand.java:222)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerCommand$1.invoke(ControllerCommand.java:68)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:131)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.node.EventBroadcasterInterceptor.invoke(EventBroadcasterInterceptor.java:124)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.PageCustomizerInterceptor.invoke(PageCustomizerInterceptor.java:134)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.PolicyEnforcementInterceptor.invoke(PolicyEnforcementInterceptor.java:78)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.node.PortalNodeInterceptor.invoke(PortalNodeInterceptor.java:81)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.BackwardCompatibilityInterceptor.invoke(BackwardCompatibilityInterceptor.java:48)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.ControlInterceptor.invoke(ControlInterceptor.java:56)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.NavigationalStateInterceptor.invoke(NavigationalStateInterceptor.java:42)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ajax.AjaxInterceptor.invoke(AjaxInterceptor.java:55)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.controller.ResourceAcquisitionInterceptor.invoke(ResourceAcquisitionInterceptor.java:50)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerInterceptor.invoke(ControllerInterceptor.java:40)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:157)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.ControllerContext.execute(ControllerContext.java:134)
    org.jboss.portal.core.model.portal.PortalObjectResponseHandler.processCommandResponse(PortalObjectResponseHandler.java:80)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.classic.ClassicResponseHandler.processHandlers(ClassicResponseHandler.java:78)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.classic.ClassicResponseHandler.processCommandResponse(ClassicResponseHandler.java:53)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.handler.ResponseHandlerSelector.processCommandResponse(ResponseHandlerSelector.java:70)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.Controller.processCommandResponse(Controller.java:315)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.Controller.processCommand(Controller.java:303)
    org.jboss.portal.core.controller.Controller.handle(Controller.java:261)
    org.jboss.portal.server.RequestControllerDispatcher.invoke(RequestControllerDispatcher.java:51)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:131)
    org.jboss.portal.core.cms.aspect.IdentityBindingInterceptor.invoke(IdentityBindingInterceptor.java:47)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.server.aspects.server.ContentTypeInterceptor.invoke(ContentTypeInterceptor.java:68)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.PortalContextPathInterceptor.invoke(PortalContextPathInterceptor.java:45)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.LocaleInterceptor.invoke(LocaleInterceptor.java:96)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.UserInterceptor.invoke(UserInterceptor.java:196)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.server.aspects.server.SignOutInterceptor.invoke(SignOutInterceptor.java:98)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.impl.api.user.UserEventBridgeTriggerInterceptor.invoke(UserEventBridgeTriggerInterceptor.java:65)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.IdentityCacheInterceptor.invoke(IdentityCacheInterceptor.java:68)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.TransactionInterceptor.org$jboss$portal$core$aspects$server$TransactionInterceptor$invoke$aop(TransactionInterceptor.java:49)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.invokeNext(TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.java)
    org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$RequiresNew.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:253)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.invokeNext(TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.java)
    org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$RequiresNew.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:262)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.invokeNext(TransactionInterceptor$invoke_N5143606530999904530.java)
    org.jboss.portal.core.aspects.server.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java)
    org.jboss.portal.server.ServerInterceptor.invoke(ServerInterceptor.java:38)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.server.aspects.LockInterceptor$InternalLock.invoke(LockInterceptor.java:69)
    org.jboss.portal.server.aspects.LockInterceptor.invoke(LockInterceptor.java:130)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invokeNext(Invocation.java:115)
    org.jboss.portal.common.invocation.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:157)
    org.jboss.portal.server.servlet.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:252)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an illegal character as your portlet instance name.